# Get height and position of status bar for api 11 so as to change its color

Tags: android, android-layout, statusbar

My app supports api 11. I need to get the hight and position of the status bar so I can change its color dynamically. I hear that some tablets have the status bar at the bottom. For that reason I need the position as well so my code can work. The following method is not sufficient for me. Will someone please propose a solution that will do what I need for api 11? I am not looking for a library, but I might be open to one.

My code:

```
final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
View view = new View(this);
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point(); display.getSize(size);
final int statusBarHeight = size.y - findViewById(R.id.rootView).getHeight();

view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, statusBarHeight));
view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dynamic_color));
    ((ViewGroup) decorView).addView(view);
```

So again, my goal is to change the color of the status bar dynamically (button click) to anything I choose. The code above is one solution I find, but it is not working for api 11

**NOTE**

Perhaps I shouldn't add this information, but most people may have the same problem. I want to be able to change the status bar color for devices older than Lollipop and so the following code is not good

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

I might not mind increasing to api 15 (though I prefer something low as 11, so far my whole app works with 11).